# How to reduce size of BIRT generated PDF with background image?

Tags: pdf-generation, birt

It seems (at least that is our understanding of the issue at this point) that given a background image in BIRT, the PDF generation routine repeats the image information inside the PDF instead of having it once referenced as the background image of all pages of the PDF.

This causes our BIRT generated PDFs to be too large. Is there a way to get BIRT to only store the image once inside the PDF and have it be the background image on each page of the PDF while keeping the file size more reasonable?

Comment: +1 Interesting question. Never noticed this myself...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, BIRT will create a new incarnation of the same background image for each page.  Unfortunately this is too deeply buried in `org/eclipse/birt/report/engine/emitter/pdf/PDFPage.java` to easily hack around nicely, and is most definitely not configurable.

But despair not!  You can use [iText](http://itextpdf.com/) (the same iText used internally by BIRT) to **eliminate duplicate entities with [`PdfSmartCopy`](http://api.itextpdf.com/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfSmartCopy.html)**.  Something along the lines of:

```
PdfReader reader  = new PdfReader(PDF_IN_FROM_BIRT);
Document document = new Document();
PdfSmartCopy copy = new PdfSmartCopy(document,
  new FileOutputStream(PDF_OUT_NO_DUPLICATES));
document.open();
for (int page = 1; page <= reader.getNumberOfPages(); page++) {
  copy.addPage(copy.getImportedPage(reader, page));
}
document.close();
```

If the above is not acceptable, then you can **patch `com.itextpdf.text.Image.getInstance(URL)` to behave in a singleton-like manner**, returning an existing `com.itextpdf.text.Image` object if the image had already been obtained from the same `URL` in the past.  You can patch and rebuild the iText JAR used by BIRT, or use [Javassist](http://www.csg.is.titech.ac.jp/~chiba/javassist/) to perform code injection at runtime without a need for recompilation.

Comment: Thanks Vlad, PdfSmartCopy was a workaround that worked well for us.